# how to move next textInput in react native

Tags: react-native

I using React Native 0.48.4.
How to select the next TextInput? i try with this below code it not working for  me

```
<TextInput 
  returnKeyType={'next'}
  secureTextEntry={true}
  style={styles.textBox}
  keyboardType = 'number-pad'
  maxLength = {1}
  autoFocus={true}
  blurOnSubmit={true}
  onSubmitEditing={(event) => { 
    this.refs.SecondInput.setFocus(); 
  }}
  onChange={this.onChangePassCode}
  onChangeText={(passCode) => this.setState({passCode})}
/>
<TextInput 
  ref='SecondInput'
  returnKeyType='next'
  secureTextEntry={true}
  style={styles.textBox}
  keyboardType = 'number-pad'
  maxLength = {1}
  blurOnSubmit={false}
  onChange={this.onChangePassCode}
  onChangeText={(passCode) => this.setState({passCode})}
/>
```

Comment: try changing `this.refs.SecondInput.setFocus();` to  `this.refs.SecondInput.focus();`

Comment: should be `this.refs.SecondInput.focus();`

Comment: i changed to `this.refs.SecondInput.focus();` that also not working

Comment: also no need to use `event` in param for `onSubmitEditing` . please remove .

Comment: that also not working, `onSubmitEditing` will work in React Native  0.48.4 ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Typical use case login and password is given below,

First, assign a variable to 'ref' call back in your TextInput component. **Note: 'ref' is now a callback function, not a direct variable which was deprecated.** Now call 'focus()' on this stored variable to focus that TextInput as given below

```
<TextInput
  keyboardType='email-address'
  returnKeyType='next'
  onSubmitEditing={() => this.passwordRef.focus()} 
  onChangeText={(email) => this.setState({email})}
/>

<TextInput
  ref={passwordRef => this.passwordRef = passwordRef}
  returnKeyType='done'
  autoCorrect={false}
  onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({password})}
/>
```

Read these docs and search for direct manipulation in react-native
https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#the-ref-callback-attribute

Comment: thank you @Ravi Raj it working for me, if any possible to move automatically to next textInput,

Comment: What do u mean by automatic?   I don't understand. U can use any number of TextInput's by using this way.

Comment: yes. for example my TextInput is `maxLength` is 2 after typing two char it must move to next TextInput if it possible?

Comment: Yes possible, u have to handle that in onChangeText function, where u check inputValue.length > 2, then u call ur required textinputRef.focus() inside that.

Comment: can pls give some example?